# Possible to execute php string?

Tags: php

If I have a variable that contains PHP code... something like this:

```
$PageCode = "<?php\r\nrequire_once(\"../code/rushs_flickr_photos.php\");\r\n?>";
```

Is it possible to execute that code within my page and assign it back to another variable? something like:

```
$PageContent = exec($PageCode);
```

Comment: Why would you want to put PHP code in a string and execute it instead of just requiring the file directly? If your answer is because you want to get the code to execute from the user, be aware this is a **huge** security issue.

Comment: If you decide to fly in the face of security, just know that you don't need opening/closing php tags in code that will be eval()'d.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. You are looking for [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php).

This is however considered *very* bad practice. Whatever it is that you are trying to do, there is most likely a better way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes look at [eval()](http://www.php.net/eval) function