# Include -- using a string rather than a filename

Tags: php, string, include, eval

I'd like to run include on a string rather than a file, but an unaware of how to achieve this.

```
//This is the desired functionality
include($filename);

//But I want to do something like this instead.
$file_contents = getFileFromCacheOrSomewhereElse($filename);
include($file_contents);  // Doens't work...
eval($file_contents);     // Also incorrect.
```

Please note:  "eval" is not the same as include -- "include" echos out the contents of the file (and executes any PHP tags) while "eval" executes the string as PHP code.

An example use case is loading a template file from Memcache (as a string), then running include on that string, rather than running include and relying on PHP filecache.

Comment: can`t you just use apc for a bytecode cache? or cache the *evaluated* template?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible to execute php string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550152/possible-to-execute-php-string)

Answer (score 10):

If you can turn `on` the `allow_url_fopen` and `allow_url_include` php.ini settings, then an alternative is the `data` stream wrapper ([manual](http://php.net/wrappers.data)).

```
include 'data:text/plain,' . urlencode($file_contents);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
eval("?>" . $file_contents . "<?php ");
```

does it.

Comment: Are you sure that in this use case eval is equivalent to include?  There are a lot of things to consider -- variable scope, error handling, etc.

Comment: No I'm not. I just tested the above line and thought that's probably sufficient for your purposes. Although I'd think in terms of varialbe scope, it is equivalent (no scope change). Error handling will probably be different.

Comment: Is this working with files that do not contains closing ?> tag?

Answer (score 1):

Storing PHP code in the memcache is not the best idea.
And evaling it thereafter is even worse.

Any opcode cache, APC or EAccelerator will cache your PHP files on the fly, with no strange efforts like this, and even parse it for the faster execution.

EDIT. Given the voting results after all these years, I assume that this question is attracting only noobs, who have the same strange whim. So I have to repeat: although it defeats your brilliant idea,

## just leave your includes as is

They will be cached much better and executed much faster by the internal PHP's [opcode cache](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.opcache.php).

Comment: Thank you for your input.  It is nice to know that that caching templates, for example, is a bad idea if an opcode cache is available.  This doesn't answer my question, though :)